# jQuery functionality

Tags: jquery

I have implemented one function by using this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

At the same time header file have jquery function. When I using

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

the header file function is not working.

If I remove this header is working well. but the page function is not working.
How can I resolve this issue?

Script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>  
<script defer src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/responsiveslides.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(window).load(function() {
      jQuery(".slides").responsiveSlides({
      auto: true,
      pager: false,
      nav: true,
      controlNav: "thumbnails",
      speed: 500,
      namespace: "flexslider",
      before: function () {
       jQuery('.events').append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
      },
      after: function () {
       jQuery('.events').append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
      }
    });
  });
 </script>
```

In header on this page the countries name will be display in drop down by using js.

Comment: Please write what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have tried only remove this script from my page. After removing this line header is working.

Comment: Please show an example of your page HTML, as where you include the script is important and your question is not clear.

Comment: means you use 2 jquery min in a page?

Comment: can you access this site? http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js, maybe your html is not downloading this api properly. please show entire html code.

Comment: I have edited code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had similar issues in the past and resolved it by changing the load order of the jquery libraries.